# Zend_DB join results into array?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, join

(solved! Thank you guys for the advice =)

$contact = $db->select('*')
                     ->from(array('c' => 'contact'), array('name', 'id'))
                     ->join(array('d' => 'detail'), 'c.id = d.contact_id', array('d.type'))
                     ->where('c.company_id = ?', $defaultNamespace->userdata['company_id'])
                     ->where('c.effective < ?', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
                     ->where('c.expire > ?', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
                     ->order('c.effective DESC');
              $stmt = $db->query($contact);
              $contact = $stmt->fetchAll();

```
          foreach($contact as &$point){

            print_r($point);

          }
```

Outputs:

Array ( [name] => John Doe [id] => 1 [type] => Skype ) Array ( [name] => John Doe [id] => 1 [type] => MSN )

I want:

Array ( [name] => John Doe [id] => 1 [point] => array(Skype, MSN) )

Comment: Your not going to be able to have zend produce that sub array for you. I'm guessing the best you could do is something like: array( [name] => John Doe, [id] => 1, [point1] => Skype, [point2] => MSN, [point3] => '' ); you could do this by joining the detail table onto the contact table a couple of times. OR loop through the results and do a sub call, but I'm guessing you'd like it in one go at the db.

Comment: You say you solved it. You should post the solution and accept it as the answer. This helps make Stack Overflow useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using custom Zend_Db_Select class. That class will take **some** of the cols and explode them using GROUP CONCAT separator and you will use group concat in your query ;) It's the only solution I can think of ;)

Answer (score -1):

In mySQL you can do something like `SELECT id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(type) FROM contact WHERE id = 3 GROUP BY id, name, type;`

Not sure it will work for you but you can try it.